Will Desktop Ubuntu 24.04.1 allow me to use KVM for VMs and Hauppauge TV tuner?
I am building new system and would like to do almost all with virtual machines.
KVM is a type 1 (base metal) hypervisor that is I believe included in Linux distributions.
Hauppauge has informed me the use of the quadHD TV tuner is not supported on a virtual machine.  It is only supported on the host (base metal) machine.
